# A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:). - Has anyone encountered this issue when using the Azure DevOps RestAPI?

Tags: powershell, api, rest, azure-devops

I am trying to create a Powershell script that will delete repos from Azure DevOps. I run a get request and then try pass the repo id to the url for the delete request, but whenever I do this I get the error "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)".

If I run the Rest call with the repo id hardcoded into it it works but I get the error when I try pass the repo id to the url - anyone know any possible work arounds?

Here is a brief example of the commands:

```
$APIUrl = "$baseUrl/$Org/$ProjectName/_apis/git/repositories/$RepoName?api-version=6.0"

$Repo = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $APIUrl -Method Get -Credential $cred -Headers $header

$DeleteUrl = "$baseUrl/$Org/$ProjectName/_apis/git/repositories/$Repo.id?api-version=6.0"

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $DeleteUrl -Method Delete -Credential $cred -Headers $Header
```

Comment: In `$DeleteUrl`, replace `$Repo.id` with `$($Repo.id)`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the way you construct this URL string:

```
$DeleteUrl = "$baseUrl/$Org/$ProjectName/_apis/git/repositories/$Repo.id?api-version=6.0"
```

Only simple variable expressions (like `$Repo`) is expanded in double-quoted strings in PowerShell, and the `.id` is ignored.

A string literal like `"/$Repo.id?api"` thus expands to a value like `/@{id=repoId; name=repoName; ...}.id?api-version=6.0` - which is why the web handler in front of AzDO complains of a "potentially dangerous path".

Use the `$(...)` subexpression operator to nest the whole expression in the string literal:

```
$DeleteUrl = "$baseUrl/$Org/$ProjectName/_apis/git/repositories/$($Repo.id)?api-version=6.0"
```